# Can one private key be associated with several public keys?

Tags: hash, cryptography, key, rsa

Ok, so my crpto lecturer in Uni posed this question at the end of the RSA key generation lecture as a brain teaser.

I have been thinking about this and I think I have come up with a way ( I am aware its not practical and very vulnerable - But I would love for you guys to punch holes through it ):

- Use RSA to generate public and private key pair.
- Make an additive hash function that taken in any input and adds the
  ascii value of each character and gives that as an output. ( I am
  aware additive hash has horrible distribution for ex ABC , BAC , ACB
  all have the same hash output -- but theoretically this can be used
  as an advantage to solve our problem )
- Now take your public key and generate several possible keys by
  jumbling up the on and off bits.
- Give these jumbled up keys to potential customers.
- Put our hash function on the server.
- When customer puts in his jumbled up public key - Hash function
  calculates the hash - which should be similar to original public key 
  generated by RSA. Customer gets access.

Once again I am aware that this is very vulnerable and terrible. It cant be used in the real world. But does it answer the question my lecturer posed ?

**EDIT:**

Guys I am sorry for the confusion. This question has nothing to do with collisions and expoiting the maths ( Those are definitely valid ways to do that - but they weren't what my lecturer was referring too - they were discussed in the lecture itself. ). The way my lecturer asked this question was - " come up with ways to make several public keys related to a single private key - nevermind how vulnerable your solution is ".

Comment: I suspect the question is more along the lines of can the math that generates the supposedly unique paring of public+private keys ever have a collision such that a key from one pair works with the opposite from another pair but is still different from the same kind in the other pair.

Comment: I see where you are going  .. but that wasn't the question posed. Question was very general and stated "Can you think of ways of generating several public keys to match up with a single private key?"

Comment: Might be better fit for http://crypto.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I know what your lecturer was getting at. I'm not going to give you the full answer but I'll lead you along a few steps. Obviously your lecturer wants you to study the math of RSA. In particular, look at the public and private exponents and how they are related. Now, suppose you have an RSA modulus N, and RSA public exponent e, and an RSA private exponent d. Is there another exponent, say e + x, that works exactly the same way as e in the RSA math? The answer is yes, there is. In fact, there is an entire family of such exponents. Now you have to discover what this x value is, and how it related to the math of RSA.

Comment: You are right ..  we discussed this in todays lecture .. Thanks a lot. basically multiples of ϕ(N) that satisfy e∗d=1modϕ(N) will produce multiple public keys for the same private key. This is also a serious security flaw in RSA .  If someone gets a hold of several public keys - they can subtract them to get to ϕ(N). And then it all  falls apart from there.... The only way around this is to have very large P,Q prime numbers and basically cross your fingers

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to spoil too much, but I think the answer your lecturer was waiting for is more related to the mathematical properties of finite groups. Maybe see [the definition of textbook RSA](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1448/definition-of-textbook-rsa) and see if you can find another public key that matches a given private key. [Fermat's Little Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_little_theorem) might also be interesting.

Answer (score 0):

While you are looking up finite groups, you want to read about equivalence classes.